# child datagridview to parent textbox winform

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have two form(frmMain and frmchild_list). When I click a button in a frmMain the frmchild_list will pop up and the data is now populate in the datagridview. If a click the data row in frmchild_list, I want to pass the  value of the selected datagridview to textbox in parent.

here my code in Parent

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(radioButton1.Checked)
     {
         f1.frmchild_list f = new f1.frmchild_list(this, "Y");
         f.MdiParent = this;
         f.Show();
     }
     else
     {
        f1.frmchild_listf = new f1.frmchild_list(this, "N");
        f.MdiParent = this;
        f.Show();
     }
}

public static string itemx
{
    set 
    {
        txtItem.Text = value;
    }
}
```

my code in child:

```
Form m_parent;
public frmIdH(Form f, string loc)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    loaddata(loc);
    m_parent = f;
}

public void loaddata(string location )
{...}

private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    m_parent.itemx = "sss";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the datagridview data through the constructor.

**Or**

Create an instance in the parent form of the child form. Then populate the datagridview. *Make sure the datagridview is public*.